# David didn't use to eat vegetables {when/since} he was a little boy

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-construction

> David didn't use to eat vegetables **when** he was a little boy.

On the condition that this sentence intends a past time meaning, which means that we finished to do something, then we can't use present perfect as seen.

> David didn't use to eat vegetables **since** he was a little boy.

Now it intends the meaning that is still in progress, David still doesn't like eating vegetables. Can you point out what I'm actually missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he still does not like eating vegetables, you have to use **"since"**,so the first sentence is correct

If you use **"when"**, it shows that he hadn't like to eat before, but now he likes

and you must say **"didn't use to"** not didn't used to

Comment: *David didn't used to eat vegetables when he was a little boy.* doesn't say anything about David at the present time. The salient interpretation, especially with *(didn't) used to*, would be what you said, however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say something about the past you can use the simpler sentence

> David didn't eat vegetables when he was a little boy.

That has no connection with the present, but you can make it so with

> . . . and he still doesn't like them.

or

> . . . but he likes them now.

Comment: David hasn't eaten vegetables since he was little.